# Render a set of 3d points as rectangles while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a set of 3d points and I want to render each of these points as rectangles(for ease). I want these rectangles to simulate the behaviour of 3d objects in a sense that they maintain aspect ratio in regards to camera. Basically I want them to do something like this:

[image]

Here is what I do: In the vertex shader I basically do nothing and just pass the vertex down the pipeline

`gl_Position = vec4(vtx_position, 1.0);`

In the geometry shader I try to generate these rectangles by projecting the input vertices to modelview space and then generating 4 output vertices with the same offset from input and emitting them after multiplying them with projection matrix:

```
uniform mat4    MV;
uniform mat4    PROJ;
uniform float   size; 


position = MV * gl_in[0].gl_Position; 

gl_Position = position;
gl_Position.xy += vec2(-size, -size);
gl_Position = PROJ  * gl_Position;  
EmitVertex();

gl_Position = position;
gl_Position.xy += vec2(-size, size);
gl_Position = PROJ  * gl_Position;  
EmitVertex();

gl_Position = position;
gl_Position.xy += vec2(size, -size);
gl_Position = PROJ  * gl_Position;  
EmitVertex();

gl_Position = position;
gl_Position.xy += vec2(size, size);
gl_Position = PROJ  * gl_Position;  
EmitVertex();
```

Finally in fragment shader I just fill them with color. However on output I get something like this:

[image]

While each rectangle is positioned correctly thir sizes are off. What did I do wrong? What should be done to achieve result like in the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out while I was searching for the problem in shades I was also multiplying size uniform with aspect ratio in c++ code.